# Java 3 level nested list to 3 level nested map

Tags: java, list, nested, hashmap, java-stream

I have a lists of lists of lists. How do I convert to map of maps of maps?

```
Public class Country{
  private String name;
  private List<State> states;
}

Public class State{
  private String name;
  private List<City> cities
}

Public class City{
  private String name;
  private List<Town> towns
}

public class Town{
  private String name;
  private Integer population;
}
```

I want a map of states of cities of towns in these formats:

1. Using the whole object as the keys:
   1st level: state -> cities. 2nd level: cities -> town.
2. Using the names as the keys:
   1st level: state's name -> city's name. 2nd level: city's name -> town

Please help, I have been trying to accomplish this by using stream, but not able to so far.

Comment: "I have been trying to accomplish this by using stream" - would you share your attempt? It might be almost complete and we would just help you to fix an error.

Comment: Also required output data structure would be nice to specify. Is it `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>`?

Comment: "Using the whole object as the keys" -> I wouldn't recommend doing that. In your model all objects just have names and children and you should _not_ use the children as part of the key (i.e. the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods). Since that leaves the names only I would just use a `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Town>>` - but how about the Town-level here? Are you actually after a 4-level map to get the population? And what are you trying to use those maps for?

Comment: An alternative approach: why don't you have the maps inside your classes already? So `Map<String, State> states;` etc. ?

Comment: I cannot modify the established data models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
Map<State, Map<City, List<Town>>> stateToCitiesToTowns =
        country.getStates().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(state -> state, state -> state.getCities().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(city -> city, City::getTowns))));

System.out.println(stateToCitiesToTowns);

Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> stateToCitiesToTownNames =
        country.getStates().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(State::getName, state -> state.getCities().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(City::getName, city -> city.getTowns().stream()
                                .map(Town::getName)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))));

System.out.println(stateToCitiesToTownNames);
```

Input:

```
Country country = new Country("CountryA", Arrays.asList(
        new State("StateA", Arrays.asList(
                new City("cityA", Arrays.asList(
                        new Town("townA", 4),
                        new Town("townB", 5),
                        new Town("townC", 42),
                        new Town("townD", 67)
                )),
                new City("cityB", Arrays.asList(
                        new Town("townE", 65),
                        new Town("townF", 14),
                        new Town("townG", 24),
                        new Town("townH", 33)
                )))),
        new State("StateB", Arrays.asList(
                new City("cityC", Arrays.asList(
                        new Town("townI", 9),
                        new Town("townJ", 5),
                        new Town("townK", 12),
                        new Town("townL", 4)
                )),
                new City("cityD", Arrays.asList(
                        new Town("townM", 5),
                        new Town("townN", 7),
                        new Town("townO", 24),
                        new Town("townP", 6)
                ))))));
```

Output (it's very long since the both key and value have same lists):

```
{State(name=StateB, cities=[City(name=cityC, towns=[Town(name=townI, population=9), Town(name=townJ, population=5), Town(name=townK, population=12), Town(name=townL, population=4)]), City(name=cityD, towns=[Town(name=townM, population=5), Town(name=townN, population=7), Town(name=townO, population=24), Town(name=townP, population=6)])])={City(name=cityC, towns=[Town(name=townI, population=9), Town(name=townJ, population=5), Town(name=townK, population=12), Town(name=townL, population=4)])=[Town(name=townI, population=9), Town(name=townJ, population=5), Town(name=townK, population=12), Town(name=townL, population=4)], City(name=cityD, towns=[Town(name=townM, population=5), Town(name=townN, population=7), Town(name=townO, population=24), Town(name=townP, population=6)])=[Town(name=townM, population=5), Town(name=townN, population=7), Town(name=townO, population=24), Town(name=townP, population=6)]}, State(name=StateA, cities=[City(name=cityA, towns=[Town(name=townA, population=4), Town(name=townB, population=5), Town(name=townC, population=42), Town(name=townD, population=67)]), City(name=cityB, towns=[Town(name=townE, population=65), Town(name=townF, population=14), Town(name=townG, population=24), Town(name=townH, population=33)])])={City(name=cityB, towns=[Town(name=townE, population=65), Town(name=townF, population=14), Town(name=townG, population=24), Town(name=townH, population=33)])=[Town(name=townE, population=65), Town(name=townF, population=14), Town(name=townG, population=24), Town(name=townH, population=33)], City(name=cityA, towns=[Town(name=townA, population=4), Town(name=townB, population=5), Town(name=townC, population=42), Town(name=townD, population=67)])=[Town(name=townA, population=4), Town(name=townB, population=5), Town(name=townC, population=42), Town(name=townD, population=67)]}}
```

Output:

```
{
 StateA=
        {
         cityA=[townA, townB, townC, townD],
         cityB=[townE, townF, townG, townH]
        }, 
 StateB={
         cityC=[townI, townJ, townK, townL], 
         cityD=[townM, townN, townO, townP]
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Both of these solutions work! I have a modified version of this question. Any help would be appreciated as well! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67619466/list-of-lists-of-lists-to-a-map-of-flatten-map-of-lists

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to add getters, setters and constructors to classes

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>> map = countries.stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getName, country -> country.getStates().stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(State::getName, state -> state.getCities().stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(City::getName, city -> city.getTowns().stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Town::getName, Town::getPopulation))))))));
```

So, I used input value from @BuildSlayer 's answer

```
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Country> countries = Collections.singletonList(new Country("CountryA", Arrays.asList(
                new State("StateA", Arrays.asList(
                        new City("cityA", Arrays.asList(
                                new Town("townA", 4),
                                new Town("townB", 5),
                                new Town("townC", 42),
                                new Town("townD", 67)
                        )),
                        new City("cityB", Arrays.asList(
                                new Town("townE", 65),
                                new Town("townF", 14),
                                new Town("townG", 24),
                                new Town("townH", 33)
                        )))),
                new State("StateB", Arrays.asList(
                        new City("cityC", Arrays.asList(
                                new Town("townI", 9),
                                new Town("townJ", 5),
                                new Town("townK", 12),
                                new Town("townL", 4)
                        )),
                        new City("cityD", Arrays.asList(
                                new Town("townM", 5),
                                new Town("townN", 7),
                                new Town("townO", 24),
                                new Town("townP", 6)
                        )))))));
        Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>> map = countries.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getName, country -> country.getStates().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(State::getName, state -> state.getCities().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(City::getName, city -> city.getTowns().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Town::getName, Town::getPopulation))))))));
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}

class Country {
    String name;
    List<State> states;

    public Country(String name, List<State> states) {
        this.name = name;
        this.states = states;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<State> getStates() {
        return states;
    }

    public void setStates(List<State> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }
}

class State {
    String name;
    List<City> cities;

    public State(String name, List<City> cities) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<City> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCities(List<City> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
}

class City {
    String name;
    List<Town> towns;

    public City(String name, List<Town> towns) {
        this.name = name;
        this.towns = towns;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Town> getTowns() {
        return towns;
    }

    public void setTowns(List<Town> towns) {
        this.towns = towns;
    }
}

class Town {
    private String name;
    private Integer population;

    public Town(String name, Integer population) {
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(Integer population) {
        this.population = population;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
{CountryA={StateA={cityA={townD=67, townB=5, townC=42, townA=4}, cityB={townH=33, townF=14, townG=24, townE=65}}, StateB={cityC={townI=9, townL=4, townJ=5, townK=12}, cityD={townP=6, townN=7, townO=24, townM=5}}}}
```

Comment: I use lombok to generate the getters and setters, and this solution works, thank you! I have a modified version of this question. Any help would be appreciated as well! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67619466/list-of-lists-of-lists-to-a-map-of-flatten-map-of-lists